# ASP.NET EFCodeFirst not using correct connection string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first

I am trying to publish a website using ASP.NET MVC3 EF and CODEFIRST with a SQL Server 2008 backend.  On my local machine I was using a sql express db for development, but now that I am pushing live, I want to use my hosted production database.  The problem is that when I try to run the application, it is still using my local db connection string.  I have completely removed the old connection string from my web.config file and am using the `<clear />` tag before creating the new connection string.  I have also cleaned the solution and rebuilt, but somehow it is still connecting to the old db.  What am I missing?

This is the new connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="CellularAutomataDBContext"
         connectionString=" Server=XXX;
         Database=CellularAutomata; User ID=XXX; Password=XXX; Trusted_Connection=False" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  
  </connectionStrings>
```

**UPDATE**

When I debug and look at the DBCONTEXT object, this is what is showing up for its connection:

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CellularAutomata.Models.D1K2N3CARuleDBContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

I am unsure why this is happening because I cannot find it being set to this anywhere.  Also, under configuration it says LazyLoadingEnabled = true, I assume this may be part of the problem, maybe it is not loading the new connection string.  Where do I change these parameters?

**UPDATE 2**

EFCodeFirst is using a default connection string, I can't figure out how to get it to accept the connection string that I specify in the web.config file.

Comment: I think that unless your local machine actually has a static IP address that you've explicitly used in the connection string, then I don't see how the published app will connect to it. Did you create the database in the AppData folder? Are you publishing that folder?

Comment: @Lirik, I haven't use any ip adress in the connection string and EFCodeFirst takes care of the database creation.  I'm really at a loss for why this is happening.

Comment: @Doug S. So that probably means that the web app is not connecting to the database on your local machine... are you publishing the AppData folder as well? Do you have something in the AppData folder?

Comment: @Lirik, There is nothing in the AppData folder.

Comment: @Doug S. DOH! Sorry, this whole time I thought that you're seeing this issue with the published website, instead you're seeing the issue while you're running/debugging it on your local machine... please disregard my previous comments!

Comment: It must be getting that connection string from somewhere... do a "find in all files" search for "SQLEXPRESS" or something else unique from that connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, When using EF CodeFirst, there is a default connection string that it uses.  If you want to be able to use a custom connection string, there are a few parameters guidelines that you must follow.

```
name ="this must match the name of your database context class"
connectionString="Server=yourserverurl; Database=yourdatabasename; User ID=youruserid; 
Password=yourpassword; Initial Catalog=the name of the database to use;
Trusted_Connection=False"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

So far this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `connectionString` you show is not an EF connection string. The EF won't use it. So you're changing the wrong thing.

An EF `connectionString` will include `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`

Comment: I'm not really sure what is going on then.  I am for sure using EFCodeFirst, and this is the only connection string I can find.  The old one used the same provider name and worked just fine.

Comment: I didn't realize.  I thought Code-First was just a part of the entity framework.

Comment: It is. But it doesn't require an EDMX file. Hence, the connection string you show *is* valid. But I wonder if you're changing the right one. If you have multiple assemblies, look for similarly-named connection strings elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It will look for the same name as your context and depending on what else you
are using other names as well. I usually use the following for controlling 
specific features with either the same or specific connection strings
(I keep app services in a different db for example so EFCF can drop tables as needed):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyAppContext" .../>
  <add name="ApplicationServices" .../>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" .../>
</connectionStrings>
```